# Continuous cleaning of Laravel cache especially for the package spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, optimization, laravel-permission

I have a problem with Laravel cache,
When I add/change the route or change the roles in the spatie/laravel-permission package, I must clear the cache,
Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

By default, it is set to 24 hours.

You can change it in the config/permissions.php file.

> The default cache expiration_time is 24 hours. If you wish to alter the expiration time you may do so in the config/permission.php file, in the cache array.

[https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/advanced-usage/cache](http://Spatie%20-%20Permissions)

Answer (score 0):

You can run these cache removing commands from your controller.

```
Artisan::call("cache:forget spatie.permission.cache"); 
Artisan::call("cache:clear");
```